# numpy alternative to pd.factorize()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Does anyone know a numpy alternative to `pd.factorize()`?

I have a need for speed in an algorithm, and would like to not use the pandas dataframe.

So for instance,

```
test = np.array(['yo', 'whats', 'up', 'whats', 'up', 'yo'])
```

shall return

```
pd.factorize(pd.Series(test))
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: `pandas.factorize` seems actually quite efficient on large datasets, check the timings in my updated answer

Comment: That is surprising. I needed to use it in some type of permutationtest, so the bottleneck was the creation of n datasets. For %timeit np.array(X)
821 ns ± 8.79 ns per loop, and for %timeit pd.DataFrame(X)
73.8 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_inverse=True`:

```
test = np.array(['yo', 'whats', 'up', 'whats', 'up', 'yo'])

np.unique(test, return_inverse=True)[1]
```

output: `array([2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])`

##### timing

`numpy.unique` is faster up to ~10k items, then `pandas.factorize` is actually faster.

The [python alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71691048/16343464) is only fast on small arrays (<100).

comparison on 1 to ~8M rows, with 8 factors
[image: comparison 1]

comparison on 1 to ~33M rows, with 52 factors
[image: comparison 2]

Comment: @Pychopath the order is arbitrary and shouldn't matter (actually the order is by lexicographic order of the words)

Answer (score 1):

Already a great answer above. Wall time for Option # 2 below was almost half:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array(['yo', 'whats', 'up', 'whats', 'up', 'yo'])
```

**Option # 1**:

```
%%time
x, y = np.unique(test, return_inverse=True)
y
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 103 µs, sys: 23 µs, total: 126 µs
Wall time: 110 µs

array([2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
```

**Option # 2**:

```
d={}
[d.setdefault(w, i) for i, w in enumerate(test)]
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 60 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 61 µs
Wall time: 64.1 µs

[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: test in 1k, 10k, 100k values.

Comment: e.g. `test = np.array(['yo', 'whats', 'up', 'whats', 'up', 'yo'] * 1000)`

Comment: @Nilesh there is an overhead of using numpy on small arrays (<100), but numpy quickly and linearly outperforms python: [see graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzvvr.png)