# Reassigning values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of class ids like this:
y = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9] (although y is actually a large 1D array)

The goal is to reassign y such that the range would be [0, 6] or [0, len(np.unique(y))].

Hardcoded solution is:

```
new_y = np.empty_like(y)
new_y[y == 1] = 0
new_y[y == 2] = 1
new_y[y == 4] = 2
new_y[y == 5] = 3
new_y[y == 6] = 4
new_y[y == 9] = 5
```

I'm trying to avoid a for-loop-if statement.
Are there some NumPy in-built functions that could help with this, and how?

Comment: Is [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @bluecouch, thanks for your comment; it gave insight into fixing it. I used np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)[1] as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690493/numpy-alternative-to-pd-factorize).